# Is Apache HTTPd able to create intermediate directories when PUTting files?

Tags: apache-2.4, http, httpd

I'm using Gradle and that is able to publish artifacts to repos using HTTP, but with the one big caveat that it's expecting a smart repository manager as target, which handles [creating intermediate directories](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/does-gradle-create-intermediate-directories-on-publish-to-ivy/6476) as [necessary](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/intermediate-ivy-directories-workaround-with-gradle-2-0/13474). Without such manager, things simply [fail](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/basic-use-case-for-publishing-to-ivy/6783) and that [issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2392) hasn't been addressed for years.

Is there anything available in HTTPd as module or stuff to simply create those intermediate directories transparently?

I didn't find anything and wouldn't like to implement something on my own, e.g. using mod_perl. Might simply be easier to use a smarter repo manager then, but if HTTPd would provide something OOB I simply missed, that might be easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of.

Simplest way is you should give permissions on the filesystem accordinly to the user httpd runs in where you need the user to create directories.

Be careful though this can be dangerous if permissions are not set carefully.

Comment: @ezra-s The problem is not about permissions, but nobody trying to create intermediate directories at all. Putting something into children of not available parent directories is what fails.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, with "Not that I know of" I meant httpd can not create intermediary directories that I know of.